# Very Slow Charging: Thinkpad X60

Tags: thinkpad

### Update

Initially, I thought my battery was at fault, but it looks like the power brick might be the problem; It charges the battery quite quickly when it is powered off; (went up by 30% in an hour)

When the laptop is running in AC, my power manager tool shows that its neither charging or discharging.

#### tlp output

```
--- TLP 0.6 --------------------------------------------
+++ ThinkPad Extended Battery Functions
tp-smapi   = active
tpacpi-bat = inactive (kernel module 'acpi_call' not installed)

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status (Main)
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/manufacturer               = SANYO 
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/model                      = 42T4632
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/manufacture_date           = 2013-10-12
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/first_use_date             = 2014-12-18
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/cycle_count                =      9
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/design_capacity            =  74880 [mWh]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/last_full_capacity         =  74880 [mWh]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_capacity         =  22910 [mWh]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_percent          =     31 [%]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_running_time_now = not_discharging [min]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_charging_time    = not_charging [min]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/power_now                  =      0 [mW]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/power_avg                  =      0 [mW]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh        =     25 [%]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh         =     50 [%]
/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/force_discharge            =      0
```

### Old Question

I picked up an old thinkpad x60 from ebay a couple of weeks back and it has been serving me well as backup computer. So I ordered a 9 cell battery for it from amazon. It says its authentic lenovo but I have no means to verify that. It gives me good back up and all but it charges very slowly.

Right now, I am not sure If I got a bad apple or if there is some tweaking that I am not aware of( this is my first thinkpad). Btw, I have attached the information of the battery using upower.

Thanks!

```
crunchbang@crunchbang:~$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
vendor:               SANYO
model:                42T4632
serial:               8883
power supply:         yes
updated:              Wed Dec 10 18:05:19 2014 (0 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
present:             yes
rechargeable:        yes
state:               charging
energy:              8.35 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         74.88 Wh
energy-full-design:  74.88 Wh
energy-rate:         11.059 W
voltage:             14.958 V
time to full:        6.0 hours
percentage:          11.1512%
capacity:            100%
technology:          lithium-ion
```

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?

Comment: This is about hardware, not about the operating system, so you'll probably get better advice on [su]. (Don't repost there, but you may want to flag your question and request that a moderator migrate your question to SU.) My hunch is that this is normal: batteries don't age well, an old battery is likely to have poor behavior. If it's a new battery (your question isn't clear), it's possible that the *first* (or first few) charging takes longer because the battery needs to be calibrated.

Comment: hmm, I figured it might be a linux specific thing. But you are right it might be a hardware thing.

Comment: Questions: 1)Is the power information at the end of the question design data pulled from the battery chip or performance data based on the charging process?  That would indicate whether a bigger power adapter might charge faster. 2)What is the actual charge time when powered on and powered off?  Is "slow" relative to the old battery or some other reference or expectation?  3)Has it gotten faster after the first few charges?  4)Are both batteries the same capacity (higher capacity = longer charge time)?  5)Is there user info on the Thinkpad with charge time expectations?

Comment: I think the battery information is real-time, its using this module called tp_smapi to provide both real-time information about power and battery status of the device. 

What information do you think will help in comparing the chargers?

Comment: Btw here is a link to the modules wiki describing different battery status features: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#Battery_status_features

Comment: Can you answer Q's 2-5?  BTW, use @username in the comment if you want the person alerted to your comment, otherwise they won't know you posted it.

Comment: @fixer1234
For question2, I do not have an exact number but it takes around 3-4 hours for the battery to charge completely when powered off.

The laptop came without a battery so I am basically comparing the charging time powered off vs powered on -- this is what I mean when I say slow.

Q3, the charging time hasn't changed much since the last month, when I purchased the battery. 

Can you explain what you mean by user-info? 
thanks!

Comment: I'm not so sure 3-4 hours for a complete charge is unusual.

Comment: @fixer1234 that's the charging time when the device is powered off. When powered on the charge rate is close to zero; I can leave it for hours but and the charge would not increase a percent.

Comment: I don't think 3-4 hrs when powered off is unusual.  If there is virtually no charging while powered on, there's a good chance the power adapter just doesn't have enough power to do both.  The least expensive next step would be to try a higher power adapter.

Comment: @fixer1234 I am beginning to think that it might be the problem, but in theory the replacement charger I have has the required specs. ( it says 90W (20V, ~4.5A)

I guess, I need start looking for a good used charger on ebay.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: user400344's answer talked about a 90W charger, which is larger than the original, and didn't indicate the kind of problem you're having.  So it's possible there's a problem with the charging circuitry inside the laptop.  The trouble is, it's probably not cost effective to fix.  The practical solution might just be to charge the battery when you're not using it and use it plugged in whenever possible.  It could explain why you got such a good deal on eBay.

Comment: If there was a problem with the charging circuitry, the battery wouldn't be charging at all right? Anyways, I will try to boot into windows and see lenovo power management can give me a little more information.

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks for the input. It was the battery :)

Answer (score 0):

Afair this laptop comes with a 65W charger. You will see faster charging with a more powerful adapter. I use one with 90W, but you should be able to go higher. Of course, there could just be a problem with your battery. Hope this helps.

Edit: using the command
$ upower -d
will yield some useful information, and you can see the current full capacity cf the design full capacity. That's a pretty good indicator of how worn down your battery is.

Comment: Thanks. I update the question accordingly. 

The battery seems fine though, Its about an year old and has not been used before.

Answer (score 0):

Try a bios update. I had a thinkpad that would not charge when it was in standby mode. A bios update cleared this up. I had the choice of a floppy or cdrom image, and my laptop had a dvd drive. For x series etc you CAN NOT use an external usb dvd :( either floppy or ultrabase. This may have changed since the x60 I had once, but don't count on it. See thinkwiki for workarounds. Just google thinkwiki.

Comment: You may be right, the unit I have is on a very early bios (1.03 from 2006). Thankfully, it came with an ultrabase so flashing shouldn't be a problem. Will update the question once I flash the bios.

Comment: Btw, I manged to upgrade the bios as well. The latest version seems to be 2.19.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its a classic case of a bad battery. It took me a while to troubleshoot the problem as I did not have a spare battery and power-charger.

After ordering a charger and a replacement battery, I was able to isolate the 9cell battery as the problem :)

Thanks for the comments guys.

Comment: Doesn't look like it.  The output from upower looks perfectly normal, though it will take 6 hours to charge.  Typically the laptop has a stated maximum draw from the DC input so if you are running it and using power for that, there will be less power available to charge the battery.

Comment: @psusi you are right about the upower output. But the problem was it changed after a few seconds. Take a look at the output from the `tlp stat -b `. It simply says that it is neither discharging nor charging.

Very rarely, it would give me a good estimate of time left to charge completely and then it says its not charging at all.

Comment: Is the system running very hot?  If the temperature gets too high that can cause the battery to stop charging.

Comment: Not a lot. It rarely goes above 50 degrees.

Comment: If that is measured in the case instead of inside the cpu itself, that is too hot and would explain why the battery stops charging.  Many laptops, thinkpads in particular, have fail thermal designs.